# Choose two columns for same purpose or it should be two different columns?

Tags: database-design

We are an ecommerce website. We provide Finance option for our stocks, we have these finance options for few stocks. We have a stock table which has two columns:

1. IsFinanceAvailable: true/false. This tells if stock has emi available or not.
2. EmiAmount: This gives emi amount if its applicable. The stock may have finance but need not have emi.

We may have a case where IsEmiAvailable is true but EmiAmount is not available, but if EmiAmout is available, IsEmiAvailable has to be set true.

Should we have two separate columns or infer all info just with EmiAmount. For example:

EmiAmount null: This means no finance

EmiAmount 0: This means finance available but no emiAmount

EmiAmount>0

Should we have two different columns or just emi amount would do? what are pros and cons?

Comment: Consider [merging your accounts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 3 states for EmiAmount (and barring other complications that may need to be added) I would be inclined to use the EmiAmount (NULL, 0, >0) to define the state.

Why add a flag (which is duplicate information) if the data itself easily describes the state that you need to know?

I greatly prefer avoiding adding duplicate data which must itself be maintained. And a single source of the status (the actual data) is all that you need.

Of course, there may be complications unmentioned that could complicate matters.

Answer (score 0):

Your method to reduce this to one column requires using a "Magic Value" of zero to indicate something special.  Theoretically you could use 999, -1 or some other unexpected value to represent the state of FinanceAvailable.  Regardless of the value chosen, I dislike this solution for four reasons.

1. Lack of clarity to future users. (confusion as T.H. said)
2. Interpretation that will be necessary anywhere IsFinanceAvailable is needed.
3. The issue that would arise if zero ever became a valid EmiAmount.
4. Eliminating this column will not have a significant impact on the size of the table or on the amount of code needed.

If you do choose to eliminate the column, you should consider creating a virtual column (oracle specific name) that codifies your interpretation of the EmiAmount column and includes a comment explaining the existence of the zero magic value.

Answer (score 0):

Having a column named "EmiAmount" that also indicates finance availability (a interrelated but separate concept from EMI if I understand your post correctly) is bound to cause confusion. Even your post seems to confuse the terms. And there's probably no compact name that can alleviate this.

If you choose to use a single column, I would at least suggest a non-nullable column, and using -1 instead of null to indicate "no finance". The reason is that it's generally best not to assign an actual meaning to null, as the standard interpretation is "data optional and not available/applicable". Also, when you can avoid nulls it's best to do so due to the complications they cause. (Note I'm not suggesting to avoid nulls when "not applicable/available" is fully valid from a data modelling standpoint, which is very frequently the case.)

Comment: "its generally best not to assign an actual meaning to null" would also apply to specific values including -1 and even more so than null.  That being said I agree with your earlier conclusion that a combined column will cause confusion.

Comment: @LeighRiffel Re: null vs -1, true it does apply but I'd say much less so, because nulls are defined with a general meaning in relational theory, and thus in the way we interpret them by default in a schema or data set. -1 (or any other artificial value that's reasonably clearly not valid) isn't as likely to have assumptions made about it. But yes, the more basic principle of avoiding magic or multiple-meaning (the 0 in this case) values of any sort in a "Amount" column we certainly agree on.